# C# class to deal with web vulnerability

Tags: c#, asp.net, security

Does anybody has ever created any class consisting of functions to deal with web security vulnerabilities.
I do know that we can do avoid by adding some config settings like validaterequest and enableheader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Microsoft's [AntiXSS library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa973813.aspx) to help.  It works more on scrubbing output before rendering the page than on scrubbing input before you insert it into the DB.

Edit: here is the [download link](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=051ee83c-5ccf-48ed-8463-02f56a6bfc09&displaylang=en), the other link is to their documentation

Answer (score 1):

Visit http://www.owasp.org and look at the AntiSamy library for validating all input. (http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_AntiSamy_Project)

While You're there, also check out ESAPI.NET (http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Enterprise_Security_API#tab=.NET) which currently has a 0.1 release.